# Can an entire phrase consisting of a noun and a prepositional phrase modifying the noun be considered the direct object?

Tags: terminology, prepositional-phrases, direct-objects

I have two questions related to the following sentence:

***I saw pictures of animals.***

My first question is, what is the direct object of the sentence?

(a) The direct object is ***pictures***.

(b) The direct object is ***pictures of animals***.

(c) Either or both ***pictures*** and ***pictures of animals*** can correctly be termed the direct object of the sentence.

My second question is whether there is a grammatical term for a prepositional phrase like ***of animals*** that modifies the direct object of a sentence, and if so, what is it?

I'm hoping to receive an authoritative reply to both questions by someone who truly understands grammatical terminology, and not a criticism of the sample sentence or a suggestion of how to rewrite or replace the sample sentence. Thank you.

Comment: (a) is correct. The direct object is the whole NP "pictures of animals". The _of_ phrase is called a 'complement' of "pictures".

Comment: There are two traditions in terminology like "direct object". The older and less useful tradition says that objects have to be words, so multi-word phrases are out. The more recent and useful tradition says that objects have to be noun phrases, which may be one word, and will always have a single head. So the better answer is (b), in modern English grammar. As to the second question, there is no particular term for a prepositional phrase modifying a direct object; prepositions can modify practically anything.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with JL's label of 'modifier' for the function of the PP "of animals". The PP is specified by the head noun "pictures" and hence is a complement, not a modifier. Most _-of_ phrases in NP structure are complements - they express a semantic argument of the head noun. I do agree that the term 'complement' is not restricted to just those PPs that occur as complement of the head noun in a direct object. Complements can occur as dependents in virtually any construction. Btw, correction to my earlier message - it should of course read (b), not (a).

Comment: @John Lawler — So in "_**I've learned a great deal about molecular biology in the past few years**_," you'd say "**_a great deal about molecular biology_**" is the direct object? Or would you include "_**in the past few years**_" as part of the direct object as well?

Comment: @Bram: No, _in the past few years_ is a temporal adverbial that's part of the verb phrase, not part of the object. You're correct about what constituent I'd call the direct object.

Comment: @John Lawler — A linguist was arguing with me yesterday (elsewhere) that "about molecular biology" modifies the verb "learned." I had suggested that it modifies the noun phrase "a great deal."

Comment: "Modify" is the wrong word to use here; you're talking about specific constituent boundaries, not a single dependency. This is complex graph theory, with multiple pathways, not a single link.

Comment: LOL – Specific constituent boundaries and complex graph theory? I'm afraid you've exceeded my linguistic terminology/jargon boundaries. Can I use "modify" as a layman's shortcut and say "about molecular biology" modifies both of them?

Comment: In your latest example, the preposition phrase "about molecular biology" is not a modifier, but a complement of "learned". "Learned" thus has two complements: the direct object "a great deal" and the PP "about molecular biology".

Answer (score 1):

The direct object is (b) the entire noun phrase (although some theoreticians worry about calling the noun a *head* of a phrase, since deep heads should be closed class, such as quantifiers).

A prepositional phrase (PP) that restricts a noun phrase (NP or *DP) is called an **adnominal adjunct** (according to Wikipedia).  A PP that modifies a predicate is called an adverbial adjunct.

The word 'modifier' is sometimes restricted to those cases where the removal of such a phrase (an adjunct) would not change the grammaticality of the sentence, while the word 'complement' is sometimes restricted to those cases where it would.